# 304 instead of 200

Tags: apache, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm using a `<video>` tag with `src` attribute. When I'm using twice the same image available from Apache2, Chrome create a new resource but doesn't when it's coming from streaming. I've checked the request and here is my point:

- From Apache : 200 HTTP response
- From streaming : 304 HTTP response

I would like to have 304 response when I'm reading content from Apache. 
I've read some articles about forcing header with `If-Modified-Since`. I don't know how to do that directly with a `<video>` content. Is that even possible?

Logs from Apache:

```
# with video
::1 - - [10/May/2016:16:34:13 +0200] "GET /my/path/myvideo.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 6578328 "http://192.168.1.67:3000/my/original/url" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"

# with image
::1 - - [10/May/2016:16:40:48 +0200] "GET /my/path/myimage.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4529925 "http://192.168.1.67:3000/my/original/url" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Have you tried with [etags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) or checked if the cache headers are correct (not expired)? 304 require the browser to cache the content.

Comment: I didn't try `etags`. How can I change headers from a simple `<video>` tag with `src` attribute?

Comment: Needs to be setup on server side. If you don't have access to do this with the apache server it could be a bit problematic. But the client can also purge content from the cache for various reason (size being one) so there is no guarantee.

Comment: I've full access to the `apache` server. I'm currently checking access logs. I've added it to my question.